# decryption requires private key and passphrase

Tags: linux, public-key-encryption, gnupg, passphrase

Is it possible to require BOTH a private key and a passphrase in order to decrypt a file using gpg? I understand I can encrypt the file twice once using the public key. Then encrypt that file with the passphrase. Is there an option in gpg that will do this in one step? Looking through the man file I only was able to find a key or passphrase. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do the oppsosite: make your private key (or a new private key) require a passphrase. Then you need both private key + passphrase to decrypt.

Comment: My private key does require me to enter the passphrass for the private key every time. I was looking for an encryption pass phrase that required both the private key (with or without its passphrase) and the passphrase I encrypt the file with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand I can encrypt the file twice once using the public key.
>   Then encrypt that file with the passphrase. Is there an option in gpg
>   that will do this in one step?

Nope. There is no such option.

(You *can* however PGP-encrypt a file with a symmetric passphrase while at the same time encrypting it to multiple recipients. This basically results in multiple copies of the session key [which is used to symmetrically encrypt the message] being encrypted via different means [potentially various public keys along with a shared passphrase]).

Comment: using the symmetric option does encrypt with a passphrase. However when decrypting its still the passphrase OR the having the private key correct?

Comment: Correct. `gpg -cer ID` would generate output that could be fully-decrypted by whatever passphrase was entered or by use of ID's private key.